# How to do substitutions using sed for windows (from cygwin) for utf16 files

Tags: windows, sed, cygwin

I am using sed from cygwin on Windows to do some substitutions in text files. Everything works fine for normal (ANSI) files, but it doesn't do anything for utf-16 files (no substitutions are made). Do you know how I can make it work for both types of files at the same time?

Comment: I ran into this when attempting to make mass search/replace edits on files saved from Microsoft SQL Server Manglement Studio.  I didn't come up with a nice solution - ended up converting everything to ASCII, but I had that option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would wrap this with iconv, like

```
  iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 <input | sed -e expr | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 >output
```